# SwiftUI View Not Updating on Button Toggle After Adding ViewModel

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a signup form for users of my app.  In the form I have two toggles.  One is a slider and the other is a checkbox.  I was able to get both of these toggles working fine and the view would update perfectly when I had all of the variables declared in the view.

I've refactored the project to move some functions and error checks into a ViewModel.  Now my toggles are no longer updating the view, but the booleans they're toggling are changing values.

While I could go and cram everything back into the view, my preference is to figure out why this isn't working and what's the best way to approach these.  I don't understand how an input field, for example, will update the View Model, but a toggle won't.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
import Foundation

class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published

var email: String = ""
var companyName: String = ""
var username: String = ""
var firstName: String = ""
var lastName: String = ""
var password: String = ""
var passwordConfirmation: String = ""
var phoneNumber: String = ""
var isConsumer: Bool = true
var isChecked: Bool = false
var showSignUpErrors: Bool = false


var category: String {
    if isConsumer {
        return "consumer"
    } else {
       return "contractor"
    }
}

var EmailisInvalid: Bool {
    if email.isEmpty || !email.contains("@") {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var CompanyNameisInvalid: Bool {
    if companyName.isEmpty && !isConsumer {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var PhoneNumberisInvalid: Bool {
    if phoneNumber.isEmpty || phoneNumber.count < 10 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var PasswordLength: Int {
    return password.count
}

var PasswordConfirmationLength: Int {
    return passwordConfirmation.count
}

var PasswordLengthError: Bool {
    if password.count < 6 || password.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var PasswordConfirmationError: Bool {
    if passwordConfirmation.isEmpty {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var PasswordMatchError: Bool {
    if password != passwordConfirmation {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

var FormIsInvalid: Bool {
    if EmailisInvalid ||
        CompanyNameisInvalid ||
        PhoneNumberisInvalid ||
        PasswordLengthError ||
        PasswordConfirmationError ||
        PasswordMatchError ||
        !isChecked
        {
            return true
        }
    return false

}

}
```

Here is my View:

```
import SwiftUI
import iPhoneNumberField

struct SignUpView: View {

@ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()

@StateObject var signupVM : SignUpViewModel

var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        VStack{
            WelcomeLogo()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            
            SignUpHeader(isConsumer: $signupVM.isConsumer)

            AccountType(isConsumer: $signupVM.isConsumer)
            
            MainFields(
                email: $signupVM.email,
                companyName: $signupVM.companyName,
                username: $signupVM.username,
                firstName: $signupVM.firstName,
                lastName: $signupVM.lastName,
                phoneNumber: $signupVM.phoneNumber,
                password: $signupVM.password,
                passwordConfirmation: $signupVM.passwordConfirmation,
                isConsumer: $signupVM.isConsumer,
                isChecked: $signupVM.isChecked
            )
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 20)
            if signupVM.FormIsInvalid {
                Button(action: {
                    signupVM.showSignUpErrors = true
                }){
                    SignUpButtonContent()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                }                    
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    print("run the signup function")
                    
                }){
                    SignUpButtonContent()
                        .background(Color("BrandOrange"))
                }
            }
            

        }.padding()
        .offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight*0.4)
    }

}
}

struct MainFields: View {

@Binding var email: String
@Binding var companyName: String
@Binding var username: String
@Binding var firstName: String
@Binding var lastName: String
@Binding var phoneNumber: String
@Binding var password: String
@Binding var passwordConfirmation: String
@Binding var isConsumer: Bool
@Binding var isChecked: Bool


var body: some View {
    if !isConsumer {
        TextField("Company Name", text: $companyName)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }

    TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    TextField("Username", text: $username)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    iPhoneNumberField("Phone Number", text: $phoneNumber)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    SecureField("Password: Minimum 6 Characters", text: $password)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    SecureField("Password Confirmation", text: $passwordConfirmation)
        .padding()
        .background(lightGreyColor)
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    Button(action:
            { isChecked.toggle()
                print(isChecked)
            }
    ){
       HStack{
        Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
          Text("By clicking the 'Sign Up' button you agree to comply with the  Terms and Conditions as well as the  Privacy Policy.")
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
       }
    }
}
}



struct SignUpHeader: View {

@Binding var isConsumer: Bool

var body: some View {
    if isConsumer {
        Text("Sign Up as a Homeowner")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    } else {
        Text("Sign Up as a Contractor")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
    }
}
}

struct AccountType: View {

@Binding var isConsumer: Bool

var body: some View {
    Toggle("Change Account Type", isOn: $isConsumer)
        .font(.title2)
        .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("BrandOrange")))
    Spacer()
}
}


struct SignUpButtonContent: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Sign Up")
        .font(.headline)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
        .cornerRadius(10.0)
}
}

struct SignUpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    SignUpView(signupVM: SignUpViewModel())
}
}
```

So both this button:

```
Button(action:
        { isChecked.toggle()
            print(isChecked)
        }
){
   HStack{
    Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
      Text("By clicking the 'Sign Up' button you agree to comply with the  Terms and Conditions as well as the  Privacy Policy.")
        .font(.body)
        .foregroundColor(.primary)
   }
}
```

and this button are no longer triggering a view update:

```
struct AccountType: View {

@Binding var isConsumer: Bool

var body: some View {
Toggle("Change Account Type", isOn: $isConsumer)
    .font(.title2)
    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("BrandOrange")))
Spacer()
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated question out of curiosity: from the spacing in `SignUpViewModel`, it looks like you mean to make all properties published. But as far as I know, in Swift, the way you do it only makes `email` published. Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth good question.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `@Published` to each variable that you want to see the changes.

```
@Published var email: String = ""
@Published var companyName: String = ""
@Published var username: String = ""
@Published var firstName: String = ""
@Published var lastName: String = ""
@Published var password: String = ""
@Published var passwordConfirmation: String = ""
@Published var phoneNumber: String = ""
@Published var isConsumer: Bool = true
@Published var isChecked: Bool = false
@Published var showSignUpErrors: Bool = false
```

Also change

```
@StateObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()

@StateObject var signupVM : SignUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()
```

> [it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)